# Assume $a$ is the rate of convergence of an algorithm, then how to understand $\frac{1}{1-a}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume $a$ is the rate of convergence of an algorithm, then how to understand $\frac{1}{1-a}$. Based on the definition, 
$$
a = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_{n}-x|^{p}},
$$
then if we take $p=1$ (linear convergence), we have
$$
\frac{1}{1-a}
  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_{n}-x|}{|x_{n}-x|-|x_{n+1}-x|}
  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e_{n}}{e_{n}-e_{n+1}},
$$
how could we understand it? Thank you very much!

Comment: I am wondering where does this question come from, in what context did you become interested in $\dfrac{1}{1-a}$?

Answer (score 0):

The expression comes from the geometric series $$1+a+a^2+a^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-a}$$

I do not know how to prove the given limit, but I think the left side of this idendity is helpful.